# Is there a way to clear form input and keep input state? (Code example within)

Tags: reactjs, onclick

I have a form that uses the current state of input fields to display values on page after submit.

The problem is that I don't want these fields to be accessible after submit.

I have already tried disabling the form after submit, but this is not enough. The user can simply press submit again and the fields will again be accessible.

```
export default class Contact extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      firstname: '',
      lastname: '',
      disabled: false,
      submitted: false
    };
  }

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  handleFreezeClick = e => {
    this.setState({ disabled: !this.state.disabled });
  };

  handleSubmit = e => {
    const {
      firstname,
      lastname,
      disabled,
      submitted
    } = this.state;
    this.setState({ submitted: true });
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  render() {
    const {
      firstname,
      lastname,
      disabled,
      submitted
    } = this.state;
    return (
        <section className="section">
          <div className="container">
            <div className="content">
              <h1>Form</h1>
              <form
                name="formtest"
                method="post"
                action="www.google.com/"
                disabled={this.state.disabled}
                onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
              >
                <div className="field">
                  <label className="label" htmlFor="firstname">
                    First Name
                  </label>
                  <div className="control">
                    <input
                      className="input"
                      type="text"
                      name="firstname"
                      value={this.state.firstname}
                      onChange={this.handleChange}
                      defaultValue="Doctor"
                      disabled={this.state.disabled}
                      required={true}
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="field">
                  <label className="label" htmlFor="lastname">
                    Last Name
                  </label>
                  <div className="control">
                    <input
                      className="input"
                      type="text"
                      name="lastname"
                      value={this.state.lastname}
                      onChange={this.handleChange}
                      defaultValue="Tenma"
                      disabled={this.state.disabled}
                      required={true}
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="field">
                  <button
                    onClick={this.handleFreezeClick.bind(this)}
                    className="btn"
                    type="submit"
                  >
                    Submit
                  </button>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>

        <section>
          <div className="container">
            <div className="content">
              {submitted ? (
                <p>{`Hello ${firstname} ${lastname}`}</p>
              ) : null}
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
```

Ideal result should clear all input fields onSubmit and still display results on page after input fields have been cleared.

Comment: Is there a reason that you don't want to disable the button instead of input fields?

Comment: Also, you don't need to bind your `handleFreezeClick` method in the button callback since you are defining it as an arrow function.

Comment: There isn't a real reason. My original decision was to disable but @Clue Mediator solved my issue.

I'm not sure if I'll ever need it but is my original request even possible? Thanks.

Comment: If you want to keep those values (for some purpose) and clear the inputs I think you can save them to another state value and clear the original state that keeps input values maybe. Your real intention is important here.

Comment: Understood, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to disable the `Submit` button as well.

```
  <button
    onClick={this.handleFreezeClick}
    className="btn"
    type="submit"
    disabled={submitted} // add it in your code
  >
    Submit
  </button>
```

Comment: Although my original question may have asked something seemingly impossible, this did solve my problem. Thank you.

Now, is it even possible to clear input and keep state of that input?

Comment: For that, You have to use different variable for display purpose.

Comment: Thank you, let's say I have another button that clears the input values. I have a handleClear function that looks like this 

```

  handleClear = e => {
    this.setState({
      firstname: '',
      lastname: '',
    });
  };
```

The button successfully clears the input values but once the fields are cleared they remain locked because they have been disabled by the submit button already. 

How can I unlock those fields?

Thanks!

Comment: Some where you need to provide the button to make it enable.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't have room to enter the button code, but it does exist.            


`<button
                    onClick={this.handleClear}
                    className="btn"
                    type="clear"
                    clear={true}
                  >
                    Clear
                  </button>`

Comment: The problem is that all fields stay disabled after the original submit is pressed. - Apologies if this requires that I create an additional thread to get an answer.

Comment: If you will create thread then it will be good to understood the requirement with sample codes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can change your handleSubmit like this way

```
    handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const {
      firstname,
      lastname,
      disabled,
      submitted,
    } = this.state;
    this.setState({ submitted: true, disabled: true });
};
```

And button tag too

```
<button disabled={this.state.disabled} className="btn">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made few changes in your code snippet-

1) Add fullName propery in this.state.

2) In handleSubmit function when you are setting the state of button submission, also set the state of fullName, firstName and lastName like below

```
const fullName = firstname + ' ' + lastname;
this.setState({ submitted: true, fullName: firstname + ' ' + lastname, firstname: '',  
lastname: '' });
```

This will clear you input fields and also we are storing input values to the field name fullName.

3) Change your binding in  . Instead of binding firstname and lastname bind it with fullName property. Like below

{submitted ? (

{`Hello ${this.state.fullName}`}

) : null}

Hope this will resolve your problem.